# 18.04.2 Server - No video over iKVM

Tags: server

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 Server on a Supermicro X11SCH-LN4F based server with a Xeon E-2176g. The server supports IPMI/iKVM.

I see video output through iKVM during the initial UEFI boot, but as soon as Ubuntu starts there is no more video.

Video worked fine during the USB install.

I tried installing with the HWE kernel.

I also tried 19.04 which I was only able to install using the `safe graphics` option.

Results of `lshw -c video`:

```
$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       description: Display controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:90000000-90ffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:8000(size=64)
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: ASPEED Graphics Family
       vendor: ASPEED Technology, Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 41
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=ast latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:91000000-91ffffff memory:92000000-9201ffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Or at least I have a work-around. It looks like a driver issue for the ASpeed AST2500 SoC. It appears that driver support is [coming in Linux 5.2](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ASpeed-New-DRM-Linux-5.2).

1. Edit grub:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

2. Add `nomodeset` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`, making the full line look like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"
```

3. Update grub:

```
sudo update-grub
```

4. Restart:

```
sudo shutdown --reboot now
```